# How do i join two text files from two different folder in PHP?

Tags: php

I am new at PHP programming. So, i would like to join two text files from two different folder.
The files look something like this.
File 1:

```
 1 M
 2 L
 3 Q
 4 V
 5 H
 6 R
 7 T
```

... and so on.

File 2:

```
-1 -2 -2 -3 -2 -1 -2 -3 -2  1  2 -2  6  0 -3 -2 -1 -2 -1  1 
-2 -2 -4 -4 -1 -2 -3 -4 -3  2  4 -3  2  0 -3 -3 -1 -2 -1  1 
-2  6 -1 -2 -4  4  0 -3  0 -3 -3  2 -1 -3 -2 -1 -1 -3 -2 -3 
 2 -3 -3 -4 -1 -2 -3 -3 -3  2  3 -3  1 -1 -3 -1 -1 -3 -2  2 
-2  3 -1 -2 -3  1 -1 -3  7 -3 -1  0 -2 -2  1  0 -2 -3  0 -3 
-2  6 -1 -2 -4  0 -1  1 -1 -4 -3  3 -2 -4 -3 -1 -2 -4 -3 -3 
-1 -2  3 -2 -2 -1 -2 -2 -2 -1  1 -2  4 -2  1  0  3 -3 -2  1
```

... and so on.

I would like it to look like this:

```
1 M -1 -2 -2 -3 -2 -1 -2 -3 -2  1  2 -2  6  0 -3 -2 -1 -2 -1  1 
2 L -2 -2 -4 -4 -1 -2 -3 -4 -3  2  4 -3  2  0 -3 -3 -1 -2 -1  1 
3 Q -2  6 -1 -2 -4  4  0 -3  0 -3 -3  2 -1 -3 -2 -1 -1 -3 -2 -3 
4 V  2 -3 -3 -4 -1 -2 -3 -3 -3  2  3 -3  1 -1 -3 -1 -1 -3 -2  2 
5 H -2  3 -1 -2 -3  1 -1 -3  7 -3 -1  0 -2 -2  1  0 -2 -3  0 -3 
6 R -2  6 -1 -2 -4  0 -1  1 -1 -4 -3  3 -2 -4 -3 -1 -2 -4 -3 -3 
7 T -1 -2  3 -2 -2 -1 -2 -2 -2 -1  1 -2  4 -2  1  0  3 -3 -2  1
```

Here is my code:

```
$files1 = glob("/the path of the first files/");
$files2 = glob("/the path of the first files/");

    foreach($files1 as $file1){
        $a = file('$file1', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
        foreach($files2 as $file2){
            $b = file('$file2', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
            foreach($a as $key => $value){
                $a[$key] = $value.$b[$key];
            }
            file_put_contents('$file2',implode("\n", $pssm1),FILE_APPEND);
        }

    }
```

The above code keep displaying this error:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 670 in C:\xampp\htdocs\mycode.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined offset: 671 in C:\xampp\htdocs\mycode.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined offset: 672 in C:\xampp\htdocs\mycode.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined offset: 673 in C:\xampp\htdocs\mycode.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined offset: 674 in C:\xampp\htdocs\mycode.php on line 11
```

Anyone can help?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: dont use `''` with variables cause they won't be parsed use "" or  `file($file1` if you don't need anything but variable value

Comment: thank you @Robert for correcting and helping..

Answer (score 1):

for the code you have provided, check if the array index id present.(your error is that only.)

```
foreach($a as $key => $value){
    if(isset($b[$key])) //  <--- check this line
        $a[$key] = $value.$b[$key];
}
```

Comment: @giegie 
 
add the answer... it will help others who is looking for this

Comment: i will post it later when i finish all the code.. because i am still working on the program, still can't get the expected result.. thank you @NiranjanNRaju

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$lines = file('file1.txt');
$lines2 = file('file2.txt');

foreach ($lines as $key => $val) {
    $lines[$key] = $val.$lines2[$key];
}

file_put_contents('final_file.txt', implode("\n", $lines));
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: i've tried this code.. and it came up with this following error "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 34620413 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\joinpssm.php on line 16". Line 16 on my code is file_put_contents('final_file.txt', implode("\n", $lines));

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared a working code. Try this

```
<?php

$file1 = file_get_contents('file1.txt');
$file2 = file_get_contents('file2.txt');

$data1 = explode("\n", $file1);
$data2 = explode("\n", $file2);

foreach($data1 as $key => $data) {
    if(!isset($data2[$key]))
        continue;
    file_put_contents('File3.txt',$data . ' ' . $data2[$key] . "\n",FILE_APPEND);
}

?>

OUTPUT:

1 M -1 -2 -2 -3 -2 -1 -2 -3 -2  1  2 -2  6  0 -3 -2 -1 -2 -1  1 
2 L -2 -2 -4 -4 -1 -2 -3 -4 -3  2  4 -3  2  0 -3 -3 -1 -2 -1  1 
3 Q -2  6 -1 -2 -4  4  0 -3  0 -3 -3  2 -1 -3 -2 -1 -1 -3 -2 -3 
4 V 2 -3 -3 -4 -1 -2 -3 -3 -3  2  3 -3  1 -1 -3 -1 -1 -3 -2  2 
5 H -2  3 -1 -2 -3  1 -1 -3  7 -3 -1  0 -2 -2  1  0 -2 -3  0 -3 
6 R -2  6 -1 -2 -4  0 -1  1 -1 -4 -3  3 -2 -4 -3 -1 -2 -4 -3 -3 
7 T -1 -2  3 -2 -2 -1 -2 -2 -2 -1  1 -2  4 -2  1  0  3 -3 -2  1
```

Here first the files are read and exploded by new line so we get a array having a single line as the values of that array.

Then we looped through first array and checked if the same line exists in the second file as well. If it does not then we continue else we write the file with the combination separated with a blank space.